# Why does C output memory location/pointers instead of the values of an array?

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I tried writing a program in C that should output something like this:

```
  A B C D E F G H
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FILA 8
#define COLUMNA 8

int main(void)
{
    int nFila = 1;
    int tablero[FILA][COLUMNA] = {};
    int i, j;
    printf("  A B C D E F G H\n");
    for (i = 0; i < FILA; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", nFila);
        nFila++;
        for (j = 0; i < COLUMNA; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", tablero[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
return 0;
}
```

However it outputs random numbers for each array index that appear to be memory adresses...
How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Check your inner for-loops condition.

Comment: `i < COLUMNA` should be `j < COLUMNA`

Comment: `for (j = 0; i < COLUMNA; j++)` - copy&paste is fine, but you should tripple-check before complaining. Learn to use the debugger! `int tablero[FILA][COLUMNA] = {};` is not valid C. You have to specify at least one element in the braces.

Comment: This is why I argue against using `i` and `j` as indexes. `i` alone is fine, but when it becomes `i`, `j`, `k`, it's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Olaf debugger doesn't throw error for that.

Comment: @DeiDei any alternatives? maybe `ii` or `jj` or more descriptive names?

Comment: @margobra8: A debugger is not for **showing** errors, that's your job! How about doing some research what it actually is for? It is a vital tool for software development and the most important to find errors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also initialize subarrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FILA 8
#define COLUMNA 8

int main(void)
{
    int nFila = 1;
    int tablero[FILA][COLUMNA] = {{},};
    int i, j;
    printf("  A B C D E F G H\n");
    for (i = 0; i < FILA; i++)
    {   
        printf("%d ", nFila);
        nFila++;
        for (j = 0; j < COLUMNA; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", tablero[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
return 0;
}
```

BTW I also fixed condition in inner loop.

Comment: 1) That's as invalid C as OPs code. 2) It is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting junk values in your output. 
 You can set all values in the array to 0 by partly initializing your array **tablero** with 0.
Accordingly all the values in the array will be initalized to 0.
`int tablero[FILA][COLUMNA] = {0};`
Also, there is a bug in your code.
Please correct your line `for (j = 0; i < COLUMNA; j++)` to : 
`for (j = 0; j< COLUMNA; j++)`

Comment: The `{}` initialiser is a compiler extension e.g. of gcc. It very well initialises the array (it's a C++ feature, which would be useful for C, too).